# 3D Bravais Lattices in terms of $\mathbb{Z}^3$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, material-science, crystals

I am looking at the definitions of Bravais Lattice on Wikipedia and I find that I can describe many of them in terms of a mathematical lattice $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

- cubic $\mathbb{Z}^3$

[image]

- body-centered cuibic $\mathbb{Z}^3 \cup (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) + \mathbb{Z}^3 $

[image]

- face-centered cubic $\mathbb{Z}^3 \cup \Big((\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 0) + \mathbb{Z}^3 \Big) \cup \Big((\frac{1}{2}, 0,\frac{1}{2}) + \mathbb{Z}^3 \Big) \cup \Big((0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) + \mathbb{Z}^3 \Big)$

[image]

Then some the other lattice can no longer be written as copies of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ but we can still use the notion of [direct sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39895/the-direct-sum-oplus-versus-the-cartesian-product-times).

- tetragonal $a\mathbb{Z} \oplus a\mathbb{Z} \oplus c\mathbb{Z}$

[image]

Maybe the other 10 types of crystals can be worked out this way.

But also I think I missed the point.  Instead of writing the Bravais lattices as [coset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory) sums of $a + \mathbb{Z}^3$ can they all be written as $\vec{v}_1 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \vec{v}_2 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \vec{v}_3 \mathbb{Z}$ for the appropriate vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all Bravais lattices can be written as linear combinations of 3 vectors with integer coefficients. Your first discovery is that you can write FCC and BCC lattices as a conventional cubic cell with a basis.